# Error in C structure pointer

Tags: c

I'm not very good in C but I'm trying to do a hashtable that contains an array with linkedlist

But I have an error in this code:

```
function (&objectA.list) // Works
hashtable->tab[1]= &objectA; // I put my list into the array 
function (hashtable->tab[1].list) // Doesnt work
```

error:

> request for member ‘list’ in something not a structure or union

Comment: You will get much clearer answers if you post declarations of `objectA`, of its type, and of `function`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two code snippets are not doing the same thing: since `.` operator has higher [*precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) (in fact, it has the highest precedence of all operators) the expression

```
&objectA.list
```

means "the address of the `list` member of `objectA`.

Your second expression takes the address of `objectA`, and then tries to pull a list from it. That is not the same thing. Assuming that `tab[1]` is properly typed to hold a pointer of `objectA`, to make the second expression behave in the way the first expression does you need to write this:

```
function (&(hashtable->tab[1]->list));
```

**Note:** Although I added parentheses for clarity, they are not required, because `->` operator is of the same precedence as the dot `.` operator.

Answer (score 0):

As dasblinkenlight says, your first line of code doesn't do what you think, since `.` binds more tightly than `&`. You're taking the address of `objectA.list`, not accessing `.list` of `&objectA`.

In your last line of code, since you have a pointer, you want to use the indirect member operator,
`->`, rather than the normal member operator, `.`. In other words, `hashtable->tab[i]->list`.

Answer (score 0):

if `tab[1]` defined as a pointer to a structure then you can't use `.` operator with it as you did in

```
function (hashtable->tab[1].list)
```

use `->` instead,  or `(*hashtable->tab[1]).list`